# Embarcadero C++ Builder TADOConnection try catch

Tags: c++, try-catch, c++builder-xe5

I write DLL with Embarcadero C++ Builder XE5.
I use TADOConnection to connect database on MS SQL Server.

```
//======
try {SQLConnection->Connected = true;}
catch(...)
{
// exception handling
};
//======
```

Everything works fine until the server is unavailable for one reason or another.
The fact that the usual method of catching exceptions (try catch) doesn't work, if you run the app not from under IDE, and the program crashes.
There is a suspicion that it's a bug in XE5.
If anyone has faced this or a similar problem and solved it, please suggest a solution.

Comment: If you do run it in the debugger what does it show at that point? It would not surprise me if it's an SEH exception (which cannot be caught with try-catch) rather than a c++ exception. Without information about what is actually going wrong there's little that can be done to help you.

Comment: In the debugger the message is '[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen(Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied'

Comment: @SoronelHaetir C++Builder's RTL catches SEH exceptions and translates them into catchable descendants of the `Sysutils::Exception` class. Use `catch(const Exception&)` instead of `catch(...)`

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: There was no the flag "Build with runtime packages" in linker options. I set it. The error was catched. But now i need to put near my dll some bpl's. It is not good.